# Video Will not Autoplay in Legacy Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I am using a video in the background of a header and ran across a bug in legacy Edge where the video will not autoplay. I have seen some reports that it could be a codec issue but I setup a reduced example with the video set to autoplay and one set to controls and you can watch it fine it just won't autoplay.

I know updating to Chromium Edge will solve this but am dealing with an enterprise client that could be on legacy Edge for some time and this is not a solution that is practical for them.

You can see the reduced example on codepen here:
https://codepen.io/zoladesigners/pen/zYrbJVY

Any insight is appreciated, thank you!

```
    <div>Autoplay</div><br/>
  <video id="bgvid" class="header__vid" tabindex="-1"  autoplay="" muted="" loop="" width="320" height="240">
    <source src="http://koonzlaw.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/koonz-header-vid-Crompressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <br/>
  <div>Controls</div><br/>
    <video id="bgvid" class="header__vid" tabindex="-1"  autoplay="" muted="" loop="" controls width="320" height="240">
    <source src="http://koonzlaw.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/koonz-header-vid-Crompressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: just as an FYI the attributes `autoplay`,`muted` etc are boolean... if they are there then they are true (so don't need the `=""`, if they are missing then assumed false

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of the MS Edge legacy browser you are using for making this test. I tested your code with the **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0** and I found that Video AutoPlay is working fine.

See here:

[image]

If you are using any older version of the MS Edge browser then you can try to update to the latest version of the MS Edge browser by updating your Windows 10 OS may help to fix your issue.